# GAE application works locally, not on appengine (remote copy)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, namespaces, google-cloud-datastore, multi-tenant

I wrote a web application with servlets and using the datastore and namespace apis.

This works great on my localhost, but never stores data on the deployed copy.

I followed the multi-tenancy with java documentation, along with another reference so that I could read xml and store it in the BigTable.

Make the class persistable:

```
`@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Layout {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private String id;'
```

Store the data:

```
`customerKey = KeyFactory.createKey(Layout.class.getSimpleName(), layout.getId());
            layout.setKey(customerKey);`
```

Now make it persistent ...

```
`pm = XMLImportPersistenceManagerFactory.get().getPersistenceManager();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            saxParser.parse(new InputSource(_URL_STRINGS), this);`
```

Then close it ...

```
pm.close()
```

The code works beautifully in my localhost. It does not work that I can see on appengine. The servlet runs, but no data is ever stored.

If you hit the url, it will say Layouts Created, and I will see a 200 in the logs, but no data. That tells me the servlet is running.
Here is my app: http://layoutimporter.appspot.com/CreateLayout?namespace=boston

Some closing details. I wrote a Namespace filter to set the namespace based on the parameter in the querystring.

I am running a warmup servlet to intialize the PersistenceManagerFactory to avoid loading requests = 1.

Any ideas on this one. I have exhausted my resources and am spooling among all the same threads that are related to "oops, I can't find your kinds ..." etc.

I tried deleting the deployed copy and starting a new deployed copy. I tried reversioning the deployed copy. No joy. I can out.print the namespaces and data after persisting it when I do so on the local copy, but not ever on the remote copy.  This is a real stumper!

Thanks!

..\Wendy

Comment: Also this is how I do the makePersistentAll (after the saxParser.parse line ... pm.makePersistentAll(layouts);

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by

1. removing the jdo 1.5 libs which were being cached in my application libraries (I had switched to v2, but they were still there.
   The way I removed them was to start a new project and copy my code over.

This revealed some issues locally, e.g. now an exception was thrown in my localhost which instructed me to enable xg transactions...

2. adding the following to the jdoconfig.xml ...

3. I am using transactions.

I don't entirely understand the solution, because the transaction is simply persisting a collection of objects of type Layout. I'm happy it works.

Now the data is being persisted on the production (remote) copy as well as my localhost, according to the namespaces.

Comment: This is what goes in the jdoconfig.xml<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>